# Mouse Cursor on tablelayoutpanel

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox, mouse-cursor, tablelayoutpanel

I have winform project that it has tablelayout panel. And i added pictureboxes to all cells.

I want the mouse cursor style to cross while on the tablelayoutpanel. So i changed cursor property of tablelayoutpanel and pictureboxes. It is working.

But while mouse pointer is switching tablelayoutpanel to picturebox, the cursor style changes to default on picturebox border line. How can i prevent that?

These are my codes;

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Change tablelayout panel cursor style to cross.
            tlp1.Cursor = Cursors.Cross;

            // Change pictureboxes cursor style to cross.
            foreach (var pb in tlp1.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>())
            {
                pb.Cursor = Cursors.Cross;
            }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Hm, intersting. One workaround may be to turn off the borders and paint them yourself, aybe like so: `private void pictureBox2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Rectangle borderRectangle = pictureBox2.ClientRectangle;
    borderRectangle.Inflate(-10, -10);
    ControlPaint.DrawBorder3D(e.Graphics, borderRectangle,
        Border3DStyle.SunkenInner);
}`

Comment: @TaW thanx for reply and your time. I tried but result is same. Plase see link. [link](https://ibb.co/pxqXjbN)

Comment: Hm, when I tried it did work: All borders off, cursors for all controls as needed. But the drawn borders overlaid the pb images.

Comment: I changed all pictureboxes borderstyle property to none. And it is worked but i want the borders to appear.

Comment: If you simply mean that the Cursor changes when you hover over the Border (1 pixel) of a PictureBox, that's non-client area, so the Control's Cursor doesn't apply. If that's the case, use a Custom Control where you draw a Border **inside** the ClientRectangle and remove the standard Border. -- That will also help in the generation of the green glowing, so you don't need to paint a Cell, just *enlarge* the PictureBox custom Border and change its color.

Comment: @Jimi there is no additional codes. I shared alls in the post. In the PrintScreen image mouse pointer is not exist, so i used external app to capture screen . The app adds green glowing around the mouse point.

Comment: "If you simply mean that the Cursor changes when you hover over the Border (1 pixel) of a PictureBox". Yes this is What i mean. I ll try your advice. Many thanx for explanations.

Comment: _but i want the borders to appear._ my code ecample uses the ControlPaint class to show a border that will always comply with the system settings.

Comment: @TaW thanx for attention again. I decided to use pictureboxes without borders.